# References for elliptic integral

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to learn more about the most general [elliptic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html), that is, an integral of the form

$$\int\frac{A(x)}{B(x)\sqrt{S(x)}}$$

where $A(x), B(x)$ are arbitrary polynomials and $S(x)$ is polynomial of degree 3 or 4. Does anyone have any references that would give information about this integral ( perhaps asymptotic behaviour?). I wish to know solely about the indefinite integral, and not any definite forms for which I have found references.

Comment: What do you mean by asymptotic behaviour? Could you also tell us more about what you would like to know? E.g. when is it expressible in terms of elementary functions (there exist algorithms to solve this problem, based on Liouville's theorem), or something else?

Answer (score 5):

The "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables" ed. Abramowitz (1965) -- many editions -- has some good reference material on elliptic integrals.

The Digital Library of Mathematical Functions has quite a complete set of notes, as well: http://dlmf.nist.gov/19

More recently I've gained institutional access to Byrd and Friedman's "[Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0)", and recommend it enthusiastically to anyone who needs to solve integrals they suspect have elliptic integral solutions. (It provides little additional information on elliptic integral properties, identities, and transformations, beyond what you may find in the DLMF.)